# Excel VBA to look for PrintArea headings and auto PageBreak

Tags: excel, printing, break, area

I have "Filling form" worksheet where user is filling information and then I have "Print version" worksheet that is actually printing. I am making "CV tool" so user is filling his personal information and then my current VBA is saving end file from "Print version" to xls. and .pdf to the same folder with certain name both files where my "CV tool" is. Some people have experience of 10 years in 10 different work places and others have been only in 2 different companies previously. So before saving to .pdf and .xls my VBA hides rows that are empty to make end result look good.

The problem is that estetically it is not so good looking because some heading of work positions are at the end of the page and work description is continuing on the next page. Is there any way to make some kind of VBA to look for each page in "PrintArea" and if certain block is not fitting to this page VBA will insert "Page Break" before it to move it to the next page?

My current macro below (`Sub doitallplease()` is main command):

```
Sub Color()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Set myRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Print version").Range("Print_Area")
        For Each cell In myRange
        myRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        If cell.HasFormula = True And cell.value = "" And cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then Rows(cell.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Next
End Sub
Sub MagicButton()
    Dim iFileName$, iRow&, iCol&, iCell As Range, iArr
    iFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\CV_" & Sheets("Filling form").Range("F7") & "_" & Sheets("Filling form").Range("F9") & ".xls"
    iArr = Array(1, 3, 4): iCol = UBound(iArr) + 1

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Print version").Copy
    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
         .Buttons.Delete '.Shapes("Button 1").Delete
         .UsedRange.value = .UsedRange.value
         .SaveAs iFileName, xlExcel8: .Parent.Close
    End With

    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Sub exportpdfthisfile()
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Print version").Select
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\CV_" & Sheets("Filling form").Range("F7") & "_" & Sheets("Filling form").Range("F9") & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
Sub doitallplease()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

      ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Print version").Visible = True


Call Color
Call MagicButton
Call exportpdfthisfile
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Filling form").Activate

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Print version").Visible = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```